# How to merge actions together?

Tags: animation

I have 3 objects which I have animated separately: the main gun, the magazine, and the arms. As you can see in the image below I have named all of the actions  ReloadUMP, with their corresponding parts:

[image]

I want to merge all 3 actions together to create **one** action called "ReloadUMP", so then I can move on to make the shooting animation and so on. I can't figure out how to merge them without changing the transformation of the arms or the magazine.

[image]

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Can you fix the url for the 3rd image?

Comment: Sorry i removed the third image , it was a duplicate of the first one by accident

Comment: Did you try the NLA editor? It's possible to bake a single new action from the blended actions, but unfortunately with a lot of sample points.

Comment: lol i dont really know how to use the nla ediot - whats a sample pont?

Comment: Op did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes i did , . ,

Comment: @Knuckles209cp so how did you do it? You may answer your question so others interested would know how

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Could you please put how you found out how to fix it in an answer? That would help others who have the same problem.